# Problem with IBDesignable on interface builder

Tags: swift

I am a new swift programmer, I am taking online course in coursera. I have a problem with the code that works in the video but not in my computer. after adding IBDesignable I cannot see what I did on Interface builder, But I can see it on simulator. In the video he can also see. But my text field shows "!!Designable"

[image]

Comment: Is this `@IBDesignable` in your main app, or in a separate framework target?

Comment: it is in the file cocoa touch, uitextfield class , and linked to class of the text

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. Your Xcode projects have “targets”, one of which is your main app. It's generally advised (though frequently overlooked) that designables should not go in your main app’s target, but rather a separate “framework target”. And once you move this IBDesignable to its own framework target, go back to IB, remove the base class name and then re-add it and it should link up again. If you continue to have problems (and designables can be flaky), it's often resolved by quitting Xcode, emptying the derived data folder, and then restarting Xcode.

Comment: Okay i will check it out  thank you :) !

Comment: I will checked what you said, and found a solution.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665826.  architecture part I said no and it worked. I am new I don't understand why :)

Comment: When you select the broken IBDesignable view, there's also a "debug" button in the inspector on the right side. You can click it to run the IBDesignable service in debug mode, which lets you catch what went wrong. I know that this works for AppKit (mac) apps, but I expect UIKit apps would have the same debugability, though I'm not sure.